# Please help identify which type of CPU architecture is used on obscure portable media players

Tags: binary-analysis, binwalk

I am trying to reverse engineer a media player with obscure SigmaTel SoCs just for fun but I didn't find very useful information.

As far as I don't know exactly what CPU architecture is used on these SoCs.

Here are the binwalk + cpu_rec outputs - example of a media player based on STMP35xx SoC:

bootmanager.sb - from DSP of STMP35xx-based player (DSP56004-compatible)

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9276          0x243C          ARM executable code, 16-bit (Thumb), big endian, at least 564 valid instructions

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             None (size=0x380, entropy=0.606236)
896           0x380           TMS320C6x (size=0x100, entropy=0.526849)
1152          0x480           None (size=0x1680, entropy=0.617841)
6912          0x1B00          TMS320C6x (size=0x80, entropy=0.570979)
7040          0x1B80          None (size=0x1400, entropy=0.624876)
```

hostlink.sb - from DSP of STMP35xx-based Portable media player (DSP56004-compatible)

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
34195         0x8593          ARM executable code, 16-bit (Thumb), big endian, at least 809 valid instructions

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             None (size=0x24000, entropy=0.559532)
147456        0x24000         TMS320C6x (size=0x800, entropy=0.642204)
149504        0x24800         None (size=0x2000, entropy=0.657037)
157696        0x26800         TMS320C6x (size=0x800, entropy=0.621518)
159744        0x27000         None (size=0x11000, entropy=0.666237)
229376        0x38000         TMS320C6x (size=0x1800, entropy=0.625215)
235520        0x39800         None (size=0x4000, entropy=0.656501)
251904        0x3D800         TMS320C6x (size=0x800, entropy=0.619983)
253952        0x3E000         None (size=0x6800, entropy=0.658247)
280576        0x44800         TMS320C6x (size=0x3000, entropy=0.678292)
```

hostrsc.bin

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1133          0x46D           ARM executable code, 16-bit (Thumb), big endian, at least 548 valid instructions

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             None (size=0xc00, entropy=0.498160)
3072          0xC00           IA-64 (size=0x100, entropy=0.121801)
3328          0xD00           None (size=0x100, entropy=0.115110)
3584          0xE00           OCaml (size=0x200, entropy=0.297187)
4096          0x1000          None (size=0x3d00, entropy=0.500052)
```

resource.bin

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
149           0x95            ARM executable code, 16-bit (Thumb), little endian, at least 506 valid instructions

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             None (size=0x30000, entropy=0.676872)
196608        0x30000         OCaml (size=0x1000, entropy=0.176639)
200704        0x31000         None (size=0x9800, entropy=0.422213)
239616        0x3A800         OCaml (size=0x2800, entropy=0.374464)
249856        0x3D000         None (size=0x35800, entropy=0.650011)
468992        0x72800         IA-64 (size=0x1800, entropy=0.388964)
475136        0x74000         None (size=0x5800, entropy=0.366840)
497664        0x79800         i860 (size=0x2800, entropy=0.510416)
507904        0x7C000         None (size=0x3c000, entropy=0.621825)
753664        0xB8000         IQ2000 (size=0x2000, entropy=0.606170)
761856        0xBA000         None (size=0x19000, entropy=0.650506)
864256        0xD3000         IQ2000 (size=0x1000, entropy=0.656057)
868352        0xD4000         None (size=0x2000, entropy=0.670506)
876544        0xD6000         IQ2000 (size=0x2800, entropy=0.647489)
886784        0xD8800         None (size=0x3f000, entropy=0.669609)
1144832       0x117800        IQ2000 (size=0x800, entropy=0.645091)
1146880       0x118000        None (size=0x16000, entropy=0.680016)
1236992       0x12E000        IQ2000 (size=0x1800, entropy=0.637937)
1243136       0x12F800        None (size=0x9000, entropy=0.515688)
1280000       0x138800        i860 (size=0x2800, entropy=0.505416)
1290240       0x13B000        None (size=0x2000, entropy=0.520863)
1298432       0x13D000        Mico32 (size=0x800, entropy=0.482741)
1300480       0x13D800        None (size=0x24800, entropy=0.597388)
1449984       0x162000        IQ2000 (size=0x800, entropy=0.632276)
1452032       0x162800        None (size=0x16000, entropy=0.649701)
1542144       0x178800        IQ2000 (size=0x800, entropy=0.607468)
1544192       0x179000        None (size=0x19800, entropy=0.650747)
1648640       0x192800        IQ2000 (size=0x5000, entropy=0.662928)
1669120       0x197800        None (size=0x16000, entropy=0.665614)
1759232       0x1AD800        IQ2000 (size=0x800, entropy=0.670895)
1761280       0x1AE000        None (size=0x14800, entropy=0.667852)
1845248       0x1C2800        IQ2000 (size=0x800, entropy=0.588944)
1847296       0x1C3000        None (size=0x2b000, entropy=0.676079)
2023424       0x1EE000        IQ2000 (size=0x800, entropy=0.624574)
2025472       0x1EE800        None (size=0x1a800, entropy=0.560986)
2134016       0x209000        IA-64 (size=0x2800, entropy=0.350932)
2144256       0x20B800        None (size=0x5800, entropy=0.348755)
2166784       0x211000        IA-64 (size=0x800, entropy=0.324605)
2168832       0x211800        None (size=0x71800, entropy=0.583669)
2633728       0x283000        i860 (size=0x800, entropy=0.355774)
2635776       0x283800        None (size=0x1800, entropy=0.357956)
2641920       0x285000        IA-64 (size=0x1000, entropy=0.353298)
2646016       0x286000        None (size=0x4800, entropy=0.349873)
2664448       0x28A800        IA-64 (size=0x1000, entropy=0.287276)
2668544       0x28B800        None (size=0x2800, entropy=0.341594)
2678784       0x28E000        IA-64 (size=0x1000, entropy=0.340884)
2682880       0x28F000        None (size=0x15000, entropy=0.509803)
2768896       0x2A4000        MMIX (size=0x800, entropy=0.560577)
2770944       0x2A4800        None (size=0x8a000, entropy=0.641322)
3336192       0x32E800        OCaml (size=0x2000, entropy=0.382561)
3344384       0x330800        None (size=0x42800, entropy=0.593790)
```

stmpsys.sb

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
314           0x13A           ARM executable code, 16-bit (Thumb), little endian, at least 575 valid instructions

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             None (size=0x5800, entropy=0.692062)
22528         0x5800          TMS320C6x (size=0x200, entropy=0.612087)
23040         0x5A00          None (size=0x4000, entropy=0.678696)
39424         0x9A00          TMS320C6x (size=0x200, entropy=0.609237)
39936         0x9C00          None (size=0x2400, entropy=0.671392)
49152         0xC000          ARC32el (size=0x200, entropy=0.618732)
49664         0xC200          TMS320C6x (size=0x200, entropy=0.597122)
50176         0xC400          None (size=0x1400, entropy=0.642002)
55296         0xD800          ARC32el (size=0x200, entropy=0.581111)
55808         0xDA00          None (size=0x7200, entropy=0.499010)
84992         0x14C00         TMS320C6x (size=0x400, entropy=0.588876)
86016         0x15000         None (size=0xb200, entropy=0.421008)
```

updater.sb - from DSP of STMP35xx-based Portable media player (DSP56004-compatible)

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
34195         0x8593          ARM executable code, 16-bit (Thumb), big endian, at least 809 valid instructions

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             None (size=0x24000, entropy=0.559532)
147456        0x24000         TMS320C6x (size=0x800, entropy=0.642204)
149504        0x24800         None (size=0x2000, entropy=0.657037)
157696        0x26800         TMS320C6x (size=0x800, entropy=0.621518)
159744        0x27000         None (size=0x11000, entropy=0.666237)
229376        0x38000         TMS320C6x (size=0x1800, entropy=0.625215)
235520        0x39800         None (size=0x4000, entropy=0.656501)
251904        0x3D800         TMS320C6x (size=0x800, entropy=0.619983)
253952        0x3E000         None (size=0x6800, entropy=0.658247)
280576        0x44800         TMS320C6x (size=0x3000, entropy=0.678292)
```

Here are the bin and sb files:https://easyupload.io/zzuycg

And also there is an output of an media player based on STMP34xx SoC:

resource.bin

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1545          0x609           ARM executable code, 16-bit (Thumb), big endian, at least 538 valid instructions

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             None (size=0x25000, entropy=0.655862)
151552        0x25000         OCaml (size=0x1800, entropy=0.213865)
157696        0x26800         None (size=0x47000, entropy=0.585404)
448512        0x6D800         OCaml (size=0x800, entropy=0.226252)
450560        0x6E000         None (size=0xa800, entropy=0.550543)
```

Here are the bin files:https://easyupload.io/jw5z4i

Datasheet:https://www.rockbox.org/wiki/pub/Main/DataSheets/stmp35xx-ds-1-03.pdf

Ref. Schematics:http://www.rockbox.org/wiki/pub/Main/HardwareSchematics/stmp3500_reference_sch_revb.pdf

Comment: Datasheet says under 2.3.1 "The on-chip DSP core is modeled exactly after the Motorola DSP56004. It supports the identical instruction set, registers, addressing modes, etc., as the DSP56000 family of digital signal processors. " An exhaustive datasheet of this processor is here: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/DSP56000UM.pdf   Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor#Architecture